# How to know if a PDF file is connecting a remote server

Tags: pdf

I received a PDF file, and suspect that it is trying to connect a remote server to track me.

I wondered if there is a way to find out if the PDF file is connecting a remote server through the Internet. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would mention that "Prevention is always better than Cure" but there are a few ways to do so. I will only mention the most obvious one here.

Scan that file for viruses before downloading, or open it in the sandbox.

If you are really bent on finding out the root cause of the problem, Packet sniffers like Wireshark should help. I don't recommend having these applications as they are commonly associated with hacking, but having an idea of the connections sent across your network would help in knowing if your PDF file is dogged.

But as always, update your Acrobat Reader to the latest version and scan your computer for viruses regularly.